# Where did my edited Question go?

Tags: discussion

I had a question the was [reviewed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/267341) and now I can't locate it.  It doesn't show up in my questions asked bin.

Comment: Hi KingAndrew -- I moved your question here, to our Meta site, because questions about how to software/site/community work should be here, rather than our main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491086/why-cant-massless-particles-travel-faster-than-light) (link viewable for 10k users only) was removed by the system automatically, aka "the Roomba." You can read more about [the automatic deletion process here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

I think the criteria that triggered your question deletion was:

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days

Comment: thanks @tpg2144.  Care to give my closed question an undelete vote??  I need some votes to undelete.  It had some interest with comments and proposed answers.  But I can't question the participants anymore.

Comment: @KingAndrew Sure -- I undeleted it, but note that it is still closed. So you'll have to work to edit the question and get it reopened. If the comments start leading to discussion/possible answers/etc, it will end up getting cleaned out again.